# I can't fix this Cannot resolve constructor BarData(java.lang.String

Tags: java, android

I have problem with data = new BarData(names, yAxis);
**Cannot resolve constructor 'BarData(java.lang.String[], java.util.ArrayList)**

I uses com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5

I'm new to this programming language, and I'm writing a diploma, but I ran into such a problem, I need to insert graphics into the program, help please.

```
private ProgressDialog pd;

ArrayList<BarDataSet> yAxis;
ArrayList<BarEntry> yValues;
ArrayList<String> xAxis1;
BarEntry values ;
BarChart chart;


BarData data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graph_temp);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(intoGraph.this);
    pd.setMessage("load");

    // Log.d("array",Arrays.toString(fullData));
    chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    load_data_from_server();
}
public void load_data_from_server() {
    pd.show();
    String url = "http://192.168.0.3/temp2.php";
    xAxis1 = new ArrayList<>();
    yAxis = null;
    yValues = new ArrayList<>();


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("string",response);

                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                            String temperature = jsonobject.getString("temperature").trim();
                            String date = jsonobject.getString("date").trim();

                            xAxis1.add(date);

                            values = new BarEntry(Float.valueOf(temperature),i);
                            yValues.add(values);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }


                    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(yValues, "temper");
                    barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 82, 159));

                    yAxis = new ArrayList<>();
                    yAxis.add(barDataSet1);
                    String names[]= xAxis1.toArray(new String[xAxis1.size()]);
                    data = new BarData(names, yAxis);
                    chart.setData(data);
                    chart.setDescription("");
                    chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
                    chart.invalidate();
                    pd.hide();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(error != null){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "err...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        pd.hide();
                    }
                }
            }

    );

    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

}


}
```

Comment: Can you show us the BarData class ? From what you say, you don't have a constructor for the types of parameter you are giving

Comment: @Lutzi I only have this class where BarData is specified...and parameters i take from my data base, i use php script for take the data

Comment: So you don't know what is BarData ? Then it's pretty normal that you use its constructor in the wrong way ... begin to search what is this class, and what are its constructor(s).

Comment: The BarData constructor takes a BarDataSet as an argument. See my answer below